# kafka overhead of topic vs partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is there any difference in the administration overhead or resource consumption between spawning a thread or a partition?
Specifically,if we scale a topic to 1000 partitions vis-a-vis 1000 topics with  1 partition each(with scope to further partition) - what would be the difference from an infrastructure pov?
This question is solely from performance,infrastructure and cluster management perspective - and not comparing the business benefits of the 2 topologies.

Comment: You aren't guaranteed message order in 1000 partitions compared to only one, and you cannot scale throughput of 1 partition beyond one consumer/producer thread. A thread is at client side, not broker side of partition management, so I don't understand first question, and "scaling a topic to 1000 topics" doesn't make sense either

Comment: From what I understand one could split topic in to multiple topics and send disjoint groups of partitions to separete topics to divide them logically and op asks if this carries much overhead.

Comment: True.In terms of zookeeper administration and resource overhead,which would be a better option is what I ask.Which is a bigger maintenance debt?